# What are some limits of Google groups?

Tags: google-groups

I read this article, which outlines some limits of Google groups for apps:
http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=167085

For instance, only 100 members are allowed in a group.

However, where can I find limits for generic Google groups (https://groups.google.com/)? What is the maximum group size? How many users can join in a single day? What are attachment limits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a lot of the relevant info in the [Google Groups FAQ](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=167085).

For example, the maximum group size is dependent on the type of Google Group you have:

> With Google Apps, **a group can contain up to 100 members**. With **Google Apps for Business and Education, there's no limit to the number of members** a group can have. However, if the group contains external members, note that there is a limit to the number of messages you can send to external recipients per day (see next question).

And attachment limits:

> Yes, the **maximum size limit for messages sent to a group is 25 MB,
>   including attachments** (the normal Gmail limit). Group owners or
>   managers can edit specific groups to set lower size limits.

More info about messages and attachments can be found on [this Google message FAQ](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=166852&from=166862&rd=1).

Comment: Thanks, that is for Google Apps groups. How about for generic Google groups though?

Comment: By "Google Apps" the referred help article refers to the also called "Google Apps for your domain" and "Google Apps free edition" by the other hand the question is about Google Groups for consumer accounts.

Answer (score 1):

## Overview

AFAIK, for Google Groups, there is no limit regarding the number of members. There are limits regarding about how and when they are subscribed to the group.

## Google Groups documentation

Bear in mind that there are two main "brands", Google Groups and Google Groups for Business.

#### Google Groups (`GG`)

Use googlegroups.com as the domain for the email address of the group.
The official documentation for end-users is in http://support.google.com/groups.
The official documentation for accessing Google Groups through scripts is in https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/groups/.

AFAIK there isn't an official documentation regarding `GG` limits.

#### Google Groups for Business (`GGB`)

Use a custom domain for the email address of the group. It has the same features as `GG` plus some other features.

The [Groups administrator FAQ](https://support.google.com/a/answer/167085?hl=en) estates a limit of 100 members for groups of "Google Apps". In that help article, by "Google Apps" they are referring to the Google Apps for your domain, free, legacy, edition. The Google Apps for Work or Education editions doesn't have a limit on the number of members for each group.

From [Groups Policies and Limits - Google Apps Administrator Help](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6099642?hl=en).

> As a security measure, all Google Apps groups have limits on message
>   activity, invitations and size, and membership. If you reach one of
>   the limits, you are prevented from the activity whose limit you
>   reached. The restriction typically lasts an hour, but can last as long
>   as 24 hours.
>
> The following limits apply for Google Apps for Work or Education
>   accounts. The value of these limits may change without notice in order
>   to protect Google's infrastructure.

Go to the above link to learn about the detailed group limits.

Documentation related to `GGB`

- [Groups - Google Apps Administrator Help](https://support.google.com/a/topic/25838?hl=en)
- [Google Apps Groups Settings API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-settings/get_started)
- [Groups in the Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/groups)
- [Groups Migration API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-migration/v1/get-start/getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create one and see if you can get more than 100 members. Or, go look through the various Generic groups and see what the largest groups are.

Apparently, there IS a difference! I see at least one group on groups.google.com that has 303 members! So, maybe no limit or a very large limit? either way, it's more than 100.

I'm sure their Google Apps for Business and Education Groups are good; and they are unlimited, as far as number of members. As for 'cost,' who knows? We would have to look up the cost.

Comment: FOUND IT! Apprently, there IS a difference! I see at least one group on groups.google.com that has 303 members! So, maybe no limit or a very large limit? either way, it's more than 100.